# Issue while upgrading a Content database : specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: sLine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have installed a new Sharepoint Server 2016 Enterprise and attached a content database to the new farm but the database stuck in compatibility mode.

When we execute the commande :

Get-SPContentDatabase -Identity EPMContentDB | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase

we get an error message "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: sLine"

See logs of the configuration wizard below : [Logs](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgmvWpLV7u23lT5aL9qUnMD6ewar)

Please help!

Comment: Did you get any errors when mounting the database? How do you see it is 'stuck in compatibility mode'. The Upgrade-SPContentDatabase CMDlet should not be used as part of the upgrade-process. Use Upgrade-SPSite instead.

Comment: I didn't get any error when mounting the database.

Comment: In check upgrade page I have for this database "is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended".

Comment: When I execute the configuration wizard I have this error : Upgrade [SPContentDatabase Name=EPMContentDB] failed. Exception : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: sLine

Answer (score 0):

As described in your Comments, your Upgrade-Process seems to be completed. Unfortunately the one line of Logs is not enough to do deeper troubleshooting. However you try the following:

Open a SharePoint Management Shell and execute the following command:
`PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install`

If this doesn't succeed in the first try, please execute the same command again! Looks useless, but saved my life dozens of time.

If this still doesn't succeed, please provide more logs. The psconfig.exe output at the end will give you advice, where to find it.

Comment: I executed the command many times and the error is the same. Please see the logs in my original post (I added the link)